# Python & Pygame: Unexpected crash during run-time

Tags: python, crash, runtime, pygame, freeze

I am currently working on a pong clone in Python using Pygame.  I am no where near an expert at the subject of programming, and have run into an error.  Whenever I run the code I currently have, which will be listed below separated by Blockquotes, the program will freeze up, and not respond.  I cannot tell what the issue may be with the little knowledge I have.  I was hoping that someone would be able to assist me on this issue.  I am currently using a tutorial to help instruct me through the making of this game, and the code looks pretty identical at this point.  I will include a hyperink to the tutorial [here](http://muagames.com/tutorials/pygame-3-pong/pygame-3-pong-step-1/).  I appreciate any and all feedback.

> 3000X_runner.py

```
import GameObj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = GameObj.Game()
    game.run()
```

> PongPaddle.py

```
import os, pygame

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, user, xy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if user == 1:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "playerPaddle.png"))
        else:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "opponentPaddle.png"))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy
        self.movement_speed = 5
        self.velocity = 0

    def up(self):
        self.velocity -= self.movement_speed

    def down(self):
        self.velocity += self.movement_speed

    def move(self, dy):
        if self.rect.bottom + dy > 720:
            self.rect.bottom = 720
        elif self.rect.top + dy < 0:
            self.rect.bottom = 0
        else: self.rect.y += dy

    def update(self):
        self.move(self.velocity)
```

> GameObj.py

```
import os, pygame, PongPaddle

class Game(object):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()

    #setup screen width/height
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()  #setups internal pygame clock

    #Mandatory silly name featuring extra numbers for game name
    pygame.display.set_caption("Hyper Pong 3000-X")

    #create background.
    self.background = pygame.Surface((1080, 720))
    self.background.fill((0,0,0)) #black background

    #draws a white line down the middle of screen
    #line(Surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect
    pygame.draw.line(self.background, (255, 255, 255), (540, 0), (540, 720), 5)
    self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))  #blits to screen

    #I shall render all the sprites here:
    self.sprites = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()

    #setting up the paddles and adding them to my sprite group
    self.player_paddle = PongPaddle.Paddle(1, (50, 200))
    self.sprites.add(self.player_paddle)
    self.opponent_paddle = PongPaddle.Paddle(2, (1030, 200))
    self.sprites.add(self.opponent_paddle)

def run(self):
    stillPlaying= True
    while stillPlaying:
        self.clock.tick(30)

        #handles our pygame events, giving us a easy to view, clutter free game loop
        stillPlaying = self.handleEvents

        #updates all of our sprites
        for sprite in self.sprites:
            sprite.update()

        self.sprites.clear(self.screen, self.background)
        dirty = self.sprites.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.update(dirty)

def handleEvents(self):
    #here we handle all of our events, such as when either player will
    #press a key to move, quit the game, etc etc.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return False

            #player1 keydown events
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                self.player_paddle.up()
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                self.player_paddle.down()

            #player2 keydown events
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.opponent_paddle.up()
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.opponent_paddle.down()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            #player1 keyup events
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                self.player_paddle.down()
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                self.player_paddle.up()

            #player2 keyup events
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.opponent_paddle.down()
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.opponent_paddle.up()

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply forgot to add () in GameObj.py after 
`stillPlaying =  self.handleEvents`
It should look like: `stillPlaying = self.handleEvents()`